# iOS objective-c How can I catch window.open event in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview, window.open

I'm developing iOS hybrid app coded by Objective-C. I want to catch 'window.open' events in UIWebView. I found this code.

```
    -(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
    {
        if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ){       
           NSLog(@"opening link");
              return NO;
         }
    ....
    ...
        return YES;
    }

    - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
        NSString * test =  [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.open = function (open) { return function  (url, name, features) { window.location.href = url; return window; }; } (window.open);"];
        //
            NSLog(@"test:%@", test);   << always print blank
    ....
    ...
    ..
    }



info.plist
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

But it catches not only 'window.open' but other link events. Some answers suggest to use 'stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString', but I didn't understand.

Could you explain it for beginners to understand easily? I just want to catch 'window.open' event in UIWebView.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use following code to detect window opening:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.open = function (open) { return function  (url, name, features) { window.location.href = url; return window; }; } (window.open);"];
```

Try to put above code below delegate method:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {}
```

Comment: I write like this.   NSString * test =  [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.open = function (open) { return function  (url, name, features) { window.location.href = url; return window; }; } (window.open);"];    But 'test' always returns blank ("")   Could you tell me more?

Comment: Is that code working? or Do you want an explanation?

Comment: where are you putting this code? inside what function?

Comment: - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSString * test =  [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.open = function (open) { return function  (url, name, features) { window.location.href = url; return window; }; } (window.open);"];
    //
        NSLog(@"test:%@", test);

Comment: Looks like every thing you wrote correct. Can you please put below code in info.plist if it's not added?

<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
     <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
     <true/>
</dict>

Comment: Added already like below    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
 </dict>    I don't know why not working.  plz help me  T T